# ASP.NET Core LinkGenerator and compile time checks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core has a useful class LinkGenerator that can generate links from controller method names.
However, this behaviour seems fragile, because it relies has string based contract that is only checked at runtime.
If I change one controller method name or one method argument name, the program will behave badly.
Ex:

```
string url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction
(
    HttpContext,
    action: "GetJobStatus",
    values: new { jobId = jobId }
).ToString();
```

Do you know a feature in ASP.NET Core to force some compile time or start time check ?
For example I would like to write:

```
string url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction
(
    HttpContext,
    actionAndValues: () => this.GetJobStatus(jobId), // compile time check (method exists and arguments are compatible)
    action: this.GetJobStatus, // at least this: compile time check (method exists)
).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the method exists, you can use the `nameof()` operator:

```cs
string url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction
(
    HttpContext,
    action: nameof(GetJobStatus),
    values: new { jobId = jobId }
).ToString();
```

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to ensure the values are correct at compile time. I'm not sure if that would help you, but there's a way to retrieve the action descriptors during the runtime. You might be able to use that to check the parameters before calling the link generator.

Something like this:

```cs
public MyController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollection)
{
    var actionDescriptor = actionDescriptorCollection
        .ActionDescriptors
        .Items
        .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
        .SingleOrDefault(_ => 
            _.ControllerName == nameof(MyController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty) &&
            _.MethodInfo.Name == nameof(GetJobStatus)
            );

    var parameters = actionDescriptor
        .Parameters
        .Where(_ => _.BindingInfo.BindingSource != BindingSource.Services) // filter parameters not coming from the route
        .ToList();

    // do something with the parameters
}
```